# Calculating the expected return of log-normal distributed random variable

Tags: matlab

Let `x` be a log-normally distributed random variable with parameters `mu=0` and `sigma=0.25`. The probability density function of `x` can be obtained with `x=lognrnd(0, 0.25)` in Matlab.

How can I calculate the expected value of x from this?

Context: `x` yields the probability of a given return for an investment, and my task is to to calculate the expected return for this investment.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate the value of y2"? It's a random variable, there's nothing to calculate. Do you mean sample some values for `y2`? Or are you trying to estimate the `mu` and `sigma` for `y2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the [expected value for a lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments) analytically if you know (or can produce) the `sigma` and `mu`:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = 0.25;
expected = exp(mu + 0.5*sigma^2)
```

With `format long` returns `1.031743407499103`.

---

You can also do it empirically:

```
number_of_trials = 1000; % Increase for more accuracy, decrease for performance
samples = lognrnd(mu, sigma, number_of_trials, 1);
expected = mean(samples)
```

I repeated this 1000 times (so 1000x1000 trials) and obtained a mean expected value of `1.031981838396974` with an error of `0.008366264395879`. Histogram of expected returns across many such experiments with 1000 trials each:

[image: Histogram for estimates of mean from each experiment]

Note how the means are normally distributed, even though the original distribution was not normal. If you try to estimate a true mean by getting the mean of a few samples, that sample mean will always be normally distributed around the true mean, no matter what your original distribution was. This is called the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).